# {"user":["This field is required."]} in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Where does Django get the User from in self.request.user?

When executing a GET request, Django sees the User, and when executing a POST request, he does not see it and throws such an error.
User information is transmitted in the cookie from the frontend.

views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework import pagination
from rest_framework.response import Response
from api.models.notes import Notes
from api.serializers.notes import NotesSerializer

class FilterNotes(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = NotesSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Notes.objects \
                .filter(user=self.request.user.id) \
                .order_by('-time')
```

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class Notes(models.Model):
    note_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, models.CASCADE, db_column='user')
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Show your models too

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `perform_create` method of view and pass the user to the serializer for saving.

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

The user field should also have a value while creating a new record as it is required.

```
class FilterNotes(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = NotesSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Notes.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)\
            .order_by('-time')
        return queryset
    
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```